# Drop columns by name that appear in multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have multiple dataframes and each has the same column names, although the contents of those columns is not necessarily the same.

I tried to loop over the columns of each dataframe and remove the column by name but this did not work. If I try the same method on each dataframe individually it works

I have the following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['John', 'Joe', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Unnamed: 0': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Luke', 'Paul', 'Jane'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Unnamed: 0': [1, 2, 3]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Sue', 'Haley', 'Erica'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Unnamed: 0': [1, 2, 3]})
```

I tried this, without success:

```
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in dataframes:
    for column in df.columns:
        if "Unnamed" in column:
            df = df.drop(column, axis = 1)
```

This did not change any of the items in `dataframes`.

However, if I say:

`df3 = df3.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis = 1)`

It returns:

```
pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Sue', 'Haley', 'Erica'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
```

Note, this also works for df1 and df2, not just df3.

Can anyone help drop the unwanted column from all of the dataframes in the list without writing one line for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
for df in dataframes:
    for column in df.columns:
        if "Unnamed" in column:
            df.drop(column, axis = 1, inplace=True)
```

problem is that you were creating new dataframes, and assigning them to `df` that was immediately discarded

Comment: I think we can get rid of the second (nested) loop: `for df in dataframes: df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed:')], 1, inplace=True)`

Comment: @tato perfect! so, `inplace=True` is implicitly returning `df` in place of each corresponding item in `dataframes`

Comment: not exactly, @berrypy, inplace=True is modifying the DataFrame object that is pointed by df in each loop iteration (i.e the original dataframes), instead of creating a new one